# Restart CSS Animation on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

How do you restart animation on a click?

The solution I have is:

http://jsfiddle.net/anoopelias/qrwxdnst/

```
$("button").click(function(e) {
  $(".flexed").removeClass("slideInAnimation");
  setTimeout(function() {
      $(".flexed").addClass("slideInAnimation");
  }, 0);
});
```

This seems to work well with Chrome, but animation happens well only first time in Firefox. What is the best way to do this?

It seems to work well in Mozilla's [developer page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation), just don't know how they do that,

Comment: which part of the developer page are you talking about that restarts an animation?

Comment: If you look for the 'iframe.live-sample-frame' section, with play and pause and restart buttons, they restart animations by removing and adding the class too. However, you do it with a settimeout of 0 -- this might be the issue. You may want to remove the class, do a requestAnimationFrame and add the class again

Comment: I tried requestAnimationFrame, it didn't fix the issue. You'll have to do a bigger timeout

Comment: The developer page you linked to does a timeout of 100ms

Answer (score 1):

I posted two attempts at the question here: http://jsfiddle.net/uome7qr2/

In one, I removed the class and added a different class, which has another (identical) animation applied to it. You need to define a second animation for this one to work - it doesn't work at all if you use the same animation.

```
$("button.1").click(function(e) {
    $flexed = $(".flexed1");
    if ($flexed.hasClass('slideInAnimation')) {
    $flexed.removeClass("slideInAnimation");
    $flexed.addClass("si2");
  } else {
     $flexed.addClass("slideInAnimation");
     $flexed.removeClass("si2");
  }  
});
```

The second one uses a 100ms timeout - I believe that 50ms will work equally well, but the link you provided uses 100ms:

```
$("button.2").click(function(e) {
    $flexed = $(".flexed2");
    $flexed.removeClass("slideInAnimation");

    setTimeout(function() {
      $flexed.addClass("slideInAnimation");
    }, 100);
});
```

If you try them both, you'll see that the 100ms animation is quite jerky. The number there is quite finicky -- even up to 10ms, the button won't always cause the animation to restart reliably, but 100ms it will restart every time.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working

this link: https://jsfiddle.net/sreejithunni/u50kg2cj/5/

```
$("button").click(function(e) {
  $(".flexed").removeClass("slideInAnimation");
  setTimeout(function() {
      $(".flexed").addClass("slideInAnimation");
  }, 100);
});
```

to work in firefox add 100 ms to the setTimeout function